# Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable. ***python-jupyter_notebook

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I was trying to create a function that accepts an input list (of mixed types), and extracts only numbers from the list.
**I keep getting this 'int' object is not subscriptable error.**

```
List = ['M',1,'N',2,'0',3.5]
a_List = [x[:3] for x in List if type(x)!= str]
print(a_List)
```

Comment: Your list has integers in it, so at some point `x` is an integer, so what `x[:3]` in this case suppose to mean?

Comment: 3 non strings. I am new at coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that point, `x` is an integer as per the condition and you cannot make slices of integer.
Try `x` instead of `x[:3]`

```
Listt = ['M',1,'N',2,'0',3.5]
a_List = [x for x in Listt if type(x)!= str]
print(a_List)
>> [1, 2, 3.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehensions.

```
List = ['M',1,'N',2,'0',3.5]
list_2 = [num for num in List if isinstance(num, (int,float))]
```

Comment: thanks now it's working fine. And was a new way too.

Comment: i'm glad it solved your problem !